# Qsort() doesn't work on a struct

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, struct, qsort

I'm currently implementing some algorithm on graphs and I use a struct to keep the information about every edge in the graph: its source vertex, its destination vertex and its weight.

I have my struct declared as following:

```
typedef struct edge {
   int data[3]; //src, dest, weight
} edge_t, *edge_p;
```

Then I create a variable pointer and allocate memory for `n` structs, where `n` is a number of edges in a graph:

```
edge_p localEdges = (edge_p)malloc(n*sizeof(edge_t));
```

Then I fill up struct `localEdges` with the values of another struct `allEdges` of the same type:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++) {
    localEdges[i].data[0] = allEdges[i].data[0];
    localEdges[i].data[1] = allEdges[i].data[1];
    localEdges[i].data[2] = allEdges[i].data[2];
}
```

And then I need to sort the contents of `localEdges` by ascending order of data[2] field (by ascending edge weight). My compare function is this:

```
int myComp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const edge_t * ptr_a = (const edge_t *)a;
    const edge_t * ptr_b = (const edge_t *)b;
    return ptr_b->data[2] < ptr_a->data[2];
}
```

And the call for the function is the following:

```
qsort(localEdges, n, sizeof(edge_t), myComp);
```

However, that doesn't work. The processed `localEdges` array has some data placed wrongly. For example:

```
localEdges[0].data[2] = 1
localEdges[1].data[2] = 2
localEdges[2].data[2] = 1
localEdges[3].data[2] = 2
localEdges[4].data[2] = 3
localEdges[5].data[2] = 3
localEdges[6].data[2] = 4
```

When it should be:

```
localEdges[0].data[2] = 1
localEdges[1].data[2] = 1
localEdges[2].data[2] = 2
localEdges[3].data[2] = 2
localEdges[4].data[2] = 3
localEdges[5].data[2] = 3
localEdges[6].data[2] = 4
```

I guess there is something with pointers, but I'm not quite confident with them.

Any suggestions? I'll Appreciate your help.

Comment: `const edges_t * ptr_a` <- where is `edges_t` declared? I only see `edge_t`. Btw, better don't use `_t` suffix for your own types, it's reserved by POSIX for future extensions.

Comment: replace `return ptr_b->data[2] < ptr_a->data[2];` with `return ptr_a->data[2] - ptr_b->data[2];`.

Comment: I assume that `n == num_edges`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. `-` in a comparison function can be dangerous, if you don't know your data, you might run in a signed overflow.

Comment: And can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Right. Some limits check should be done. Yet to have some ordering negative values better to be returned.

Comment: @EugeneSh corrected some variables, sorry for misleading

Comment: @EugeneSh. of course, OPs code definitely doesn't fit the bill ;)

Comment: So should I provide an example of how this does not work?

Comment: @Indie_Cube yes, you should. It's called a [mcve].

Comment: Please do not use these `edge_p` types; `edge_t *` is *much more readable*.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, the problem is solved using solution by @FelixPalmen !

Comment: Don't cast the output of `malloc` in C!

Comment: Also, why do you have such an awkward struct definition. If you want a three element array, use a three element array. If you want a struct use a struct. You can have three fields: `int src`, `int dest` and `int weight`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist what do you mean? Sorry I didn't get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Your comparison function is wrong. Citing [a `qsort()` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second. If two members compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is undefined.

So, if you're returning `0`, the two elements are considered equal.

```
return ptr_b->data[2] < ptr_a->data[2];
```

This line **does** return `0` if the value in `*ptr_b` is greater than that in `*ptr_a`.

The correct way to do it is as follows:

```
int myComp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const edge_t * ptr_a = (const edge_t *)a;
    const edge_t * ptr_b = (const edge_t *)b;
    if (ptr_a->data[2] < ptr_b->data[2]) return -1;
    if (ptr_a->data[2] > ptr_b->data[2]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (7.22.5.2 The qsort function)

> 3 The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according
>   to a comparison function pointed to by compar, which is called with
>   two arguments that point to the objects being compared. **The function
>   shall return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if
>   the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second.**

Thus define the function for example the following way

```
int myComp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const edge_t * ptr_a = (const edge_t *)a;
    const edge_t * ptr_b = (const edge_t *)b;

    return ( ptr_b->data[2] < ptr_a->data[2] ) - ( ptr_a->data[2] < ptr_b->data[2] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your comparer function is incorrectly implemented. It never returns negative result, just bool value (comparison operation) converted to 0 and 1. Could you try something like that:

```
int myComp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const edge_t * ptr_a = (const edge_t *)a;
    const edge_t * ptr_b = (const edge_t *)b;
    return (ptr_b->data[2] < ptr_a->data[2]) ? -1 : 
        (ptr_b->data[2] > ptr_a->data[2]) ? 1 : 0;
}
```